# How do I chain 'classes' in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In create js I can create new instances of 'sub classes', eg:

```
var test = new createjs.Container();
```

I want to do something similar where I have 'gui' as the 'namespace' and my functions below, so I would be able to create new gui objects like so:

```
var obj = new gui.window();
```

How would I construct this object in javascript? I have tried a few patters, but can never access the methods with the gui class. For reference this is my latest attempt:

```
var gui = function(){
    var window = function(){
        console.log("I'm alive");
    }   

    return {"window" : window() }
}

var instance = new gui.window();
```

When I run this I just get the error gui.window() is not a function.

Comment: just remove brackets `return {"window" : window }`

Comment: why not just `return window`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox because in this case you can't do `gui.window` so `gui()` would be same `window`

Comment: Incase I wanted multiple 'sub classes' such as gui.window(); gui.alert(); gui.popup(); - I thought I would need to return a single object with access to all of these....